# Как перехватывать С2DM-увдомления, приходящие на телефон?

Tags: android-sdk, java

Возможно ли на android-телефоне программно перехватывать все С2DM(push) уведомления, приходящие на телефон? Если да, то в какую сторону следует копать.

Comment: Копайте в сторону поиска в гугл. android receive push notifications Верхняя ссылка ведет на [стек]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378671/push-notifications-in-android-platform) с ответом на вопрос.

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/qa/21235/

Comment: Я, возможно, не совсем корректно выразился, но речь идет не о c2dm уведомлениях как таковых, а о перехвате абсолютно всех c2dm уведомлений (в первую очередь - других приложений), которые приходят на телефон. Фейсбучные, контактовские, почтовые, etc.

Comment: ну наверно надо сделать свой бродКастРесивер и попросить его о перехвате абсолютно всех c2dm уведомлений...

Answer (score 1):

Пример, исходники вопроса по перехвату C2DM (на основе как нетрудно догадаться `BroadcastReceiver`) [смотрите здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814817/c2dm-broadcast-receiver)